# flutter NetworkImage of CircleAvatar

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to replace the NetworkImage of CircleAvatar with an Icon only on error.
This is 　part of my code.

```
var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final docRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);

  docRef.get().then(
    (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
   .
   .
   .
                     child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 40,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          data["imageUrl"],
                        ),
                      ),
```

I heard that Image.network has an errorbuilder property, but it is not applicable to CircleAvatar's backgroungImage.

Comment: Use this package it will help you.
Package:- https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using CircleAvatar and NetworkImage, you can use this:

```
Container(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      height: 80,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
      child:
          Image.network('image url', errorBuilder: (context, object, trace) {
        return Icon(Icons.error);
      }),
    )
```